# Click on button of a Buster Captcha Solver extension

Tags: jquery, button, recaptcha

I'm using a extension called Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans, and i need a script to use in Tampermonkey. I need it to click automatically in button to solve recaptcha, everytime it appears.

All that i know is the element of button, but i don't know how to proceed.

The script i'm trying:

```
window.onload=function(){


 setInterval(autoClick,100);


 }

 function autoClick(){
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("").length>0){

  document.getElementsByClassName("")[0].click();

 }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code

Comment: <div class="button-holder"><button class="rc-button goog-inline-block" tabindex="0" title="Solve the challenge" id="buster-button"></button></div>

Answer (score -1):

You can select element by Id and click

```
window.onload=function(){


 setInterval(autoClick,100);


 }

 function autoClick(){
  if(document.getElementById("buster-button") !== null){

  document.getElementById("buster-button").click();

 }

}
```

Also, you can do the same selecting class

```
window.onload=function(){


 setInterval(autoClick,100);


 }

 function autoClick(){
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("rc-button").length>0){

  document.getElementsByClassName("rc-button")[0].click();

 }

}
```

Comment: Still don't working. When i try using another button like reload/audio in recaptcha, works very well, but with this button in particular don't work. look the source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAWsY.png

Comment: I assume your button is inside an iframe which is why javascript can't find the element by tag name :)

Comment: @Tamim any solution for this issue?